# is it possible to lower the priority of the replication process in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

we're planning on running transactional replication of a part of our database for some near-time reporting.

I'm not quite sure which process will run to 'do' the replication, but is it possible to give this process a lower priority then sql server in case sql server has a heavy load, that the replication will not interfear with production crud actions?

Michel

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is to put the distribution database on the reporting server & have it as a configured as pull subscription to your prod db.
The 2nd option is to tweak the [log reader agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146878.aspx) parameters so that it does not generate too much overhead. This can affect how behind your reporting is from your prod.